# Parse Cloud Code authentication issue

Tags: parse-platform, ssl-certificate, parse-cloud-code

I have a Cloud Code function that makes a request to an external API.

I am passing an api key in the header as required by the third party API. When I perform the same request using curl the response is as expected and the relevant data is returned.

When I call it in Cloud Code I get the following error:

**Request failed; 60-111 Peer certificate cannot be authenticated with given CA certificates; Connection refused**

My Cloud Code looks like this:

```
Parse.Cloud.httpRequest({
    url: "https://api.endpoint.url",
    headers: {
        "ApiKey": "api-key-example"
    }
}).then(function(httpResponse){
    console.log(httpResponse);
    response.success(httpResponse.text);
}, function(err){
    console.log(err);
    response.error(err);
});
```

Comment: Does `https://api.endpoint.url` have a valid SSL certificate?

Comment: Yes I can confirm that the api has a valid SSL certificate.

Comment: What does a test on https://www.ssllabs.com/ssltest/ show?

Comment: When I run a test it comes back as Grade B

Comment: The api's SSL was provided by GeoTrust Global CA.

Comment: It's a Root 2 - GeoTrust Global CA certificate. Perhaps's parse's certificates are not up to date?

Comment: Did you get this to work? I have the same problem while calling my own Parse site via HTTPS. I have uploaded our certificate and private key to the Parse app settings.

Comment: It ended up being an issue with the certificate on the API server. It had been configured incorrectly. As soon as it was fixed, everything worked as expected.